# allocate memory with copy-on-write

Tags: c, linux, malloc

I need to implement a large in-memory key-value store which maintains system runtime data. The main thread (or let's call it transaction thread) frequently updates the key-value store and a checkpointing thread takes a snapshot of the key-value store and dump to disk every several minutes. Now I hope that the checkpointing thread can take the snapshot without pausing the transaction thread. As I searched the Internet, we may simply call fork() to get a consistent snapshot of the parent process. However for some reasons fork is not allowed in my program. So I am looking for some other solutions to tackle this problem. One possible solution is that we map a file to the virtual memory using mmap() with MAP_SHARED in the transaction thread, and then map the same file using mmap() with MAP_PRIVATE in the checkpointing thread. Unfortunately, as I have tested, the updates performed by the transaction thread will still be observed by the checkpointing thread. This is because of the following [reason](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html):

> ```
>   MAP_PRIVATE
>               Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the
>               mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the
>               same file, and are not carried through to the underlying
>               file.  It is unspecified whether changes made to the file
>               after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.
> ```

I am wondering if there exists any other solutions to handle this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Implementing a key-value store is not trivial, is there a reason you can't use one of the existing (like [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis))?

Comment: The key-value store I implemented is actually a very simple one -- without all kinds of complex techniques adopted in Redis :P

Comment: Updated answer for non-Redis case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing this yourself, I would suggest you look into using Redis which is a very quick in-memory key-value store. It also offers persisting of the data:

http://redis.io/topics/persistence

> The RDB persistence performs point-in-time snapshots of your dataset
>   at specified intervals.

**Edit:** In the case where you don't want to use Redis, you mention the following:

> Now I hope that the checkpointing thread can take the snapshot without
>   pausing the transaction thread

You cannot do this - you will need some sort of thread synchronization in place to ensure no writes are happening while you are cloning the data structure. You seem to be ok with attempting to fork() your process, which also pauses your transaction thread, and forking is actually much heavier than simply implementing a synchronization lock between multiple threads.